# Header and Footer not applying css in pdf generated by puppeteer

Tags: html, css, node.js, puppeteer

I am adding header and footer template to the pdf generated by puppeteer but the css which I added is not applied totally.

```
await page.pdf({
  path: filePath,
  format : 'A4',
  printBackground : true,
  margin : { top : 35, bottom: 45},
  displayHeaderFooter : true,
  headerTemplate : `
    <div style="height: 20px; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between; font-size: 6px; font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; letter-spacing: 0.5px;">
      <span class="date"></span>
      <span class="title"></span>
      <span class="pageNumber"></span>
    </div>`,
  footerTemplate : `<span class="pageNumber" style="font-size: 20px;"></span>`
})
```

I have tested in browser this html was giving correct output. Moreover `font-size` was responding but not as in browser. i.e. I gave `font-size : 16px` in browser, it showed perfecly but with same value in pdf generated the font was too big.

Thing which I expected to work was `justify-content` but instead everything was on left side.

Which all css will it respond to?

Comment: um your font size is 6 px is that just a typo?

Comment: no. this is the size which I gave in puppeteer after 16px as it was too big

Comment: ok then can you just try using the template in the html file itself

Answer (score 0):

try to add `width: 100%` in the div style

```html
<div style="width: 100%; display: flex; align-items: center; justify-content: space-between;">
```